# Pendrive in readonly mode

Tags: usb, readonly, usb-drive

Yesterday I started a large file transfer from my old pendrive to desktop and during the transfer my son deleted the file in source. After that my pendrive enter in readonly-mode.

I tryed change your flag into the diskpart, but don't work.

```
diskpart
select disk X
attributes disk clear readonly
```

Have something can I do to resolve it?

Thanks,

Matheus Sanches

Comment: Try formatting USB drive in Linux, or try with some low level format utility!

Comment: Do you know any low level format utility?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this low level format utility,

http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/

using this it will recreate all tracks & sectors on drive, in short it will reformat drives physical geometry.

Or

You can try formatting it in Linux,

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1
```